# OpenLayers + GeoServer problem with WFS projection

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, coordinate-system, overlay

In GeoServer I have a layer in EPSG:26191. In OpenLayers I add it on map as WFS:

```
markerLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Markers',{
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
             srsName:   "EPSG:900913",
             version:   "1.0.0",
             url:       "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/copro/wfs",
             featurePrefix: "copro", 
             featureType:   "st",  
             featureNS:     "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/copro", 
             geometryName:  "geom",  
        }),
        projection:new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),

    });
app.mapPanel.map.addLayers([markerLayer]);
```

> I used QGIS with OpenLayers plugins the overlay is perfect but with
>   this code my WFS is sent to ocean

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that WFS 1.0.0 does not support reprojection of the coordinates. If you switch your request version to 1.1.0 then GeoServer will take your srs into account.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered your problem previously and I managed to fix it using this method which I hope works for you too.

I added my file to ArcMap and, while the overlap is fine, I exported each layer, and in the export dialog I selected Use Same Coordinate System as the Data Frame.

I then added the exported layers again to GeoServer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @PolyGeo Hi,Actually I tried to answer the question..I have to use past verb.."I had your problem"..I will edit my answer to make it more clear

Comment: I hope you do not mind me doing a further quick edit.  It was your first sentence that made me think your intention was to comment upon rather than answer the question.

Comment: @PolyGeo no problem my friend,I am new here and I must pay more attention on sentences that I write.Thanks for your helps

Comment: dont worry Majid. Some people are just to serious